# On Close: MsgBox("Do you want to Save?") or MsgBox("Do you want to quit w/o saving?")

Tags: user-interface

Which is better approach and why.

Comment: Just make sure you don't take a positive response (ie. Yes) and perform a negative action (ie. Quit without saving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MsgBox(“a file has been modified. Do you wish to save before quitting?”)

With the following options

- Save and Quit (default, left position)
- Cancel (Center position, next to left button)
- Discard (right position, with an amount of spacing between the other buttons and this one.)

```
    The file xxx.txt has been modified.
    Do you wish to save before quitting?
```

+---------+                     +--------+ +-------------+
| Discard | <---- SPACING ----> | Cancel | | Save & Quit |
+---------+                     +--------+ +-------------+

NEVER EVER place the discard in between the other buttons, as this will give problems when miss-clicking. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html

Comment: It's important to note this is the way to ask on a Mac; having the buttons in this order on Windows would be out of place.  See @.yahoo.co.jpaqwsykcj3aulh3h1k0cy6nzs3isj's answer.

Comment: Not only on a Mac, but on (at least) ubuntu also.
The way it is usually asked on windows is the worst way (read [the blogpost by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) ) as the discard button is in the center!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of a yes/no question, use a question with custom buttons:

```
The file blah.txt has been modified. Would you like to save or discard it?

+------+    +---------+    +--------+
| Save |    | Discard |    | Cancel |
+------+    +---------+    +--------+
```

Comment: +1; this is the appropriate way to pose the question.  The buttons are where most users expect them to be and do what users would expect them to do.

Comment: And more importantly, the Cancel button gives the user a way out if they don't actually want to quit.

Comment: The destuctive action is placed in the middle... that is asking for trouble! ( [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114917/on-close-msgboxdo-you-want-to-save-or-msgboxdo-you-want-to-quit-w-o-savin/3114968#3114968) )

Answer (score 3):

You should seek out the UI guidelines for the platform you are developing on (search for "human interface guidelines" or "look and feel design guidelines").  If they exist, you should follow them so your app is likely to conform to the user's expectations.  For example, Apple has [specific guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BACJGAAI) for what to do in this situation on Mac OS X.

The typical advice for this particular scenario is not to have "Yes" or "No" buttons, but buttons that describe the action they perform.  For example, you can display a message box like: "Document a.txt has been modified.  Save changes?" with the buttons "Save", "Exit without saving", and "Cancel".  This makes it clear to the user what each button will do.

Comment: You can find [Microsoft's UX guidelines here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) (it's a 46 MB PDF).

Answer (score 2):

Your application should, as one of its primary goals, NEVER lose user's data. One way to accomplish that is saving regularly the work the user has done **without user intervention**.

That's the paradigm most people are used to in real life. When people write in a notebook they don't expect the paper to ask "Do you want me to actually commit these changes to paper?", they expect the changes to be permanent unless they choose explicitly to throw them away.

So, I wouldn't even ask that question, implement a robust undo functionality, and merely ask (maybe at the beginning of the work session) for a new save file name if it's a new work, saving continuously and upon exit.

These ideas come from the very enlightening [Why Software Sucks... And What You Can Do About It](http://www.rollthunder.com/Books/WhySoftwareSucks/why_software_sucks.htm).

Comment: I strongly disagree - in most other applications (at least on Windows and Mac), "Yes" **saves** the work.  You'll find you have very grumpy users if you switch the meaning of Yes and No on them.

Comment: @josh3736: That might be true, but the fundamental problem is having to ask a question. This whole "save? Yes/No" paradigm is flawed. I'll remove that sentece because it seems to distract from the main message

Comment: Fair enough, even though I'm not sold on your main point either.  I think Word has a good model.  It saves to scratch files (in case it or the computer crashes), but if you're dissatisfied with the changes you've made, just close and discard.  You could argue to continually save and allow the user to revert to a previous save, but I think that goes against the mental model most people have when it comes to editing files.  (How many would know you *can* revert?)

Comment: It might be "flawed" (and I agree with you on that)... but most users expect specific behaviour. Changing it in this case will leave them wondering if their work actually did save or if it somehow got lost. Or it'll leave them annoyed because all they did was "bump" the exit button :)

Comment: @josh3736: That model you mention this approach would be against was created in the first place due to software not adapting to the people, but the other way around. It's not there because it's intuitive or the natural way, @Matthew: The argument about user expectations is mute. While true, those expectations are there only because everybody does it the wrong way, not because the model is better. If implemented properly (there are a few tools out there that do it now) users will not notice.

Answer (score 1):

Something else I personally think is important is setting focus to whichever button is the equivalent to cancel. I think a lot of users get accustomed to these kind of prompts and just hit enter without even reading what is on the dialog. When they do this I think in most situations it's better to play it safe and cancel than to commit something.

Answer (score 0):

I hate being asked if I want to save, personally. If I needed to I probably did. If I've forgotten then most programs I use have an auto-save feature.

The idea about seeking out UI guidelines is good, but I agree with the person who suggested minimal user intervention. His analogy about writing on paper hit the nail on the head. Many programs come with some sort of version control these days.